# SQL Server encryption : create key inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create a stored procedure that allows our password custodian to recreate the symmetric key in our `DR` database, but somehow it always complains about incorrect syntax. Is this allowed in SQL Server 2008 R2 or it is just incorrect syntax ? Thanks

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BCPRecreateEncryption] 
    @Password varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DROP SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyName
    DROP CERTIFICATE EncryptCert
    DROP MASTER KEY

    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = @Password

    CREATE CERTIFICATE EncryptCert
        WITH SUBJECT = N'EncryptCert', START_DATE = N'08/06/2014 07:16:08', EXPIRY_DATE = N'08/06/2042 07:16:08'
        ACTIVE FOR BEGIN_DIALOG = ON;

    CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyName
        WITH KEY_SOURCE = @Password, 
                IDENTITY_VALUE = @Password, 
             ALGORITHM = AES_256
        ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptCert;
END
```

I also tried to use `executesql` but still get the same error

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Password string' ;

EXECUTE sp_executesql N'CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = @DCMPassword', @ParmDefinition , @DCMPassword=@Password
```

Edited to add error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BCPRecreateEncryption, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near '@Password'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BCPRecreateEncryption, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near '@Password'.

Comment: please post the exact error

Comment: `string` isn't a valid SQL datatype  ;-)

Comment: Looks like parameters are not supported for this. You could try creating the entire literal string and execute that string with `EXEC` but you'd need to watch out for any `'` characters in the password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you cannot use variables to set passwords; they need to be string literals. If you look at the MSDN page for just [CREATE MASTER KEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174382.aspx) you will notice that there is no option to pass in a local variable for the `password`. The documentation for [CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188357.aspx) also shows that only string literals are valid for `KEY_SOURCE` and `IDENTITY_VALUE`.

A secondary issue with your attempt to fix via Dynamic SQL is that `string` is not a valid datatype.

If you want to get the value from a stored procedure input parameter, then you will need to concatenate that value into the Dynamic SQL. Be sure to sanitize for single-quotes first ;-) to avoid SQL Injection issues.

```sql
SET @Password = REPLACE(@Password, N'''', N'''''');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '''
  + @Password
  + N''';';

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create variable @sql with placeholders and then using `REPLACE` fill them.

This approach is slightly better vs string concatenation because there is less double and quad - `'`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    N'CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''@DCMPassword''';

SELECT @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@DCMPassword', @Password);

EXEC(@sql);
```